# Mongoose $addToSet return new list entrys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question working with mongoose 4.0.1

I am trying to add new picture objects to an array inside a model. This is the code of my endpoint that is actually doing the job:

```
// Add new images
exports.pictures = function(req, res) {

    Incident.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        {$addToSet: {"pictures": {$each: req.body}}},
        {new: true},
        function(err, incident) {
            if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
            return res.send(201).json(incident.pictures);
        }
    );
};
```

The problem: The callback object (incident) stores all information of the model which was found and updated. But I want to return only the new array entries which were created.

How can I receive the actual changes of the operation instead of the whole object that is storing the pictures array?

Comment: I think there is no function to do it in mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new schema for pictures and adding a reference to the incident model.

The endpoint changed as well:

1. Create new picture instances for a array of pictures
2. Find incident by id
3. Save the references of the picture instances to a array inside the incident
4. Return the id of the picture instances

```js
var _ = require('lodash');

// Add new images
exports.pictures = function(req, res) {

    Picture.create(req.body, function(err, pictures) {
        if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }

        Incident.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {$addToSet: {"pictures": {$each: pictures}}},
            function(err) {
                if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }

                var pictureIds = _.map(pictures, '_id');
                return res.status(201).json(pictureIds);
            }
        );
    });
};
```